# How can I get the actual data size per row in Hive SQL?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, nosql

It is possible to calculate what is the actual data size per row in Hive SQL?
I have found [this DBA question for MS SQL Server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25531/how-can-i-get-the-actual-data-size-per-row-in-a-sql-server-table). I am not able to translate the accepted answer to Hive SQL.

I'm interested to compute the row IN-MEMORY size -- not the disk space usage per row. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: row in memory size depends also on in which object it is stored. It can be hashtable, it can be RDD, etc. Save it as a file and check the size, multiply two, take it as estimation.

Comment: You can refer to this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67725200/how-to-calculate-size-of-the-one-record-in-hive/67726266#67726266

Answer (score 0):

```
hadoop fs -du -s /hive/warehouse/managed/dp_oi.db/ | sed -r 's/ .*//g' | awk '{space+=$1} END{printf("%d GB\n",space/1024/1024/1024)}'
```